# Набирать обороты

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, общие-вопросы

Можно ли сказать: "Ремонт **всё больше и больше** набирает обороты"? Или это неправильное словосочетание?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно сказать:"Ремонт всё более и более набирает обороты"

"Всё более и более" употребляется в зн. частицы и указывает на нарастание или убывание признака, состояния и т.п., например: Отношения становились всё более и более прохладными.

Также обороты можно набирать активно, быстро, уверенно и даже стремительно.

ПРИМЕРЫ

Рынок современных окон в России все более набирает обороты.

Он смог вернуться в бизнес и теперь уверенно набирает обороты.

Рынок подержанных шин в последнее время весьма активно набирает обороты.

Comment: Благодарю за оперативность. Меня тоже очень смущало это сочетание "всё больше и больше"... Интуитивно это чувствовала!